# Access to some values from another class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableViewCell class like this:

```
class CampaignsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var activateButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleCampaignPlaceholder: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        setUpButton()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    private func setUpButton(){
        activateButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        activateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        activateButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        activateButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    }
}
```

And, in another class which is a ViewController I have my UITableView methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let rowNumber = indexPath.row
    let cellIdentifier = "CampaignTableViewCell"
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CampaignsTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCellController.")
    }

    cell.titleCampaignPlaceholder.text = campaignsArray[rowNumber].campaignName


    return cell
}
```

I need to use my activateButton in my UITableView method in order to access to campaignsArray. I have another method which requieres values from that array, so I need that method is called every time activateButton is pressed from my UITableView.

Any idea ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I like doing in those cases where you have a button inside your UITableViewCell is the following:

Give the cell a closure that is called when tapping on the button like so

```
class CampaignsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   ... all your code....

   // give your cell a closure that is called when the button is pressed    
   var onButtonPressed: ((_ sender: UIButton) -> ())?

   @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {  // wire that one up in IB
       onButtonPressed?(sender)
   }
 }
```

and then inside your TableViewController

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CampaignsTableViewCell

cell.titleCampaignPlaceholder.text = campaignsArray[rowNumber].campaignName

cell.onButtonPressed = { [weak self] sender in
    // Do your magic stuff here
}

return cell
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Interesting aproach! Can you access indexPath in the closure? Have a +1 :D

Comment: Sure you can... :)

Comment: Awesome mate!! It works properly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JavierSanzRozalén if you used Georg solution you should accept this one :)

Answer (score 3):

Your cell will get that event, not `tableView`. What you need to do is:

Create protocol inside your cell:

```
protocol CampaignsTableViewProtocol{
    func actionButtonPressed(row: Int)
}

class CampaignsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var activateButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleCampaignPlaceholder: UILabel!
    // keep info about row 
    var rowIndex: Int = -1
    // create delegate that will let your tableView about action button in particular row
    var delegate : CampaignsTableViewProtocol?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        setUpButton()
        self. activateButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.activatePressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func activatePressed(){
         self.delegate?.actionButtonPressed(row :rowIndex)
    }

    private func setUpButton(){
        activateButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        activateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        activateButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        activateButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    }
}
```

Your tableViewController needs to adopt this protocol:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CampaignsTableViewProtocol {
// rest of the code
}
```

Also, you will need to implement delegate function in your tableViewController:

```
func actionButtonPressed(row: Int) {
    // get campaign you need
    let campaign = campaignsArray[row]
    // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Also a valid possibility to work with a protocol! I personally prefer the closure a bit more, as it's less "conforming to hundreds of protocols" when you just want to get one button tab

Comment: Agree, I was just writing you the comment :) Usually it wont be just one button press, but I agree, sometimes it can be hundreds of unnecessary protocols

Comment: Hey bro, I'm trying to use this code for something similar. But the equivalent function "actionButtonPressed" is not being called. Any idea ?

Comment: Have you assigned delegate correctly? in Cell for row at index path method you need cell.delegate = self